# how to create script tag with a src from a var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, createelement

hi i need to add create script tag from this var:

```
var m ="<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>"
```

and i need it to work for example this jquery link i need it to be work so if i write any jquery code it will work.
i tried many codes such as:

```
m = m.replace(/<script src="|<script src='/g,"");
m = m.replace(/"><\/script>|'><\/script>/g,"");
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = m;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

but nothing worked.

this is the full code :
[index.html](https://jsfiddle.net/kmreddragon2/xfehwdLb/)
[code.html](https://jsfiddle.net/kmreddragon2/jbcapd84/)

Comment: `script.src = $(m).attr('src')`

Comment: is there a way without using jquery ?

Comment: `var d = document.createElement('div'); d.innerHTML = m; d.childNodes[0].src;` Of course, you could at that point just append `d.childNodes[0]` to the head.

Comment: Basically, using regexp to parse html is almost always a bad idea. In this case you're trying to strip an attribute value out of an html string, so the course of action should be to parse the html string and then get the attribute value. However, since parsing the html string gives you the node you are trying to append, you can skip a step and just append that node rather than creating another.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oodyop6b/

Comment: Can i ask why you are taking part of a string to insert into a tag thats the exact same as your string?

Comment: ok because if i used eval() it wont work

Comment: if you noticed that with eval() i can take just the code with out the src. and plz if i am wrong tell me

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var m ="<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = m;
```

Be warned this will not work when inserting into some tags in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Was this helpful? Not? Have questions? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression isn't well defined.. you can do as follow:

```
m = m.match(/'.+'/g).map(function(s){return(s.substring(1,s.length-1))});
```

What this line do?

Simple: It will take *all characters (.+)* between single quotes.

The result of *m* will be an array with all matches

---

After your existing code:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = m[0];
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

You should have a function for checking your added library:

```
function isOk (callback) {
    if (window.$) callback($);
    else window.setTimeout(function(){isOk(callback);}, 100);
};
```

and then you can use it:

```
isOk(function($) {
    $("body").html(m[0]);
});
```

[Check live here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jmz21jg1/1/)

Comment: but it will take the single quotes as well

Comment: and what about this code var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = m;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); is it right

Comment: this my full code please see it: index.html [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kmreddragon2/xfehwdLb/) code.html [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kmreddragon2/jbcapd84/)